# Cannot get Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 8

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

First off, I want to apologize if this is a duplicate. I feel like I have scoured the internet and the forums here for an answer but none of the suggestions or how to guides are helping. Now, onto the problem.

My Ubuntu CD will not boot, no matter what I do. Every time I try to boot from a CD/DVD or USB, Windows 8 boots instead. I have already disabled Fast Start Up in my Power Options; I have disabled Secure Boot in my BIOS (I even left it enabled to see if that would work); I changed my boot up options in the BIOS to load either a CD/DVD or USB first (depending on which one I was using at the time); I used the boot up options menu to select which device I wanted to load from; I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit AND 13.10 64-bit, created separate CD/DVDs of each, and even created a bootable USB device for each one (I was hoping that one of the CD/DVDs or USB sticks would work). I re-downloaded and re-created bootable CD/DVDs and USB sticks (after formatting the USB sticks), hoping that it was just a download error or image burn error that prevented from the CD/DVDs and USBs from not booting. I tried wubi, which will not fully install for whatever reason. I even updated my BIOS, hoping that would fix some kind of boot up problem. I just can't figure out why Ubuntu will not load.

I managed to get it to install when I changed to Legacy mode, but in order to go between the two operating systems, I'd have to change the BIOS from UEFI to CSM or vice versa. Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong? I've dual booted Windows Vista and Ubuntu, and Windows 7 and Ubuntu in the past and it never caused any problems for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite s55t-A5277 with Intel Core i7, 12 GB RAM, and 1 TB HDD (100 GB of which is partitioned for Ubuntu, if I can ever get it installed).

I appreciate any and all help I can get. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I figured it out. For some reason, when I tried to install Ubuntu under Legacy mode, it wasn't recognizing the partition I made in Windows. I had to go back into Windows, delete the made partition, and re-partition my hard drive. Then I had to install Ubuntu under Legacy mode, and repair the boot record to boot under EFI mode. Finally, I got it to install (but I had to do some other troubleshooting). Thank you for all of your help, Jbuch14! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In your BIOS, have you tried turning Legacy Boot Mode on (assuming of course you have this option)? Its an odd setting to have to turn on, but it was the only way I could get 13.10 installed on my Laptop.

Comment: Yes. I changed the BIOS to CSM boot (or Legacy Boot), and it installed but I need Windows 8, which can only boot in UEFI mode. So, it's a bit of a pain to install since I have to switch between the 2 constantly. I was hoping to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: Hmm. One second, ill see what I can figure out.

Comment: Booting from an Ubuntu 13.10 DVD, I am able to boot with UEFI on, and Legacy support turned off. I have, in the past however, had to boot with UEFI off, Legacy on, then after installation, I could set things back to Defaults no harm done. Im not sure if a simple fix would fix it, but it may be worth a shot. If not, sorry I wasnt of much help.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I did already try that =( Unfortunately, I get an error (I can't remember what kind). My laptop apparently really does not want Linux on here, which sucks cause I love Ubuntu.

Comment: If you were brave enough, id recommend taking the step and using Ubuntu as your main OS. I took the plunge last year (12.04) and havent gone back to windows since. Unless of course you need windows. Ill keep digging though, and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Not sure if you have viewed this [Site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) or not, but if you scroll down a bit, there is a piece about EFI (UEFI) booting, might be of some assistance.

Comment: Also, read the top answer on this [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) . Toward the end, it talks about a command called `Boot Repair`  . Hopefully one of these two threads will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately I need Windows for certain things and it's easier to have Windows 8 already installed. Otherwise I'd just use Ubuntu. I did look at that first site you linked, but I missed the part about converting Ubuntu into EFI mode (probably because I was so aggravated by that time). I'll try that and let you know how it works. Thank you Jbuch!

Comment: Just a brief follow up to see how you made out. Hopefully everything worked out for you.

Comment: It didn't work. I can't get Ubuntu to install on a separate partition without erasing Windows 8. I know if I install it under Legacy mode, then it won't have access to the EFI partition I made for Ubuntu in Windows but I can't make a Legacy partition during the Linux installation. Good news, though. I forgot to change my boot mode from UEFI to CSM, and booted up Ubuntu 12.04. It brought me to the GRUB menu, but it wouldn't install or even let me try Linux. But that's better than before. I'm going to keep playing with it, and maybe one of these times I'll get lucky. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

@user238125

Not too long ago I managed to configure a Toshiba Satellite C55-A5310 to dual boot. The following references aided me immensely. Thus I have shared them with you.

**References:**

1. [Dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu-12-10 in uefi mode Install Ubuntu](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/12/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04-in-uefi-mode/)
2. [Linux alongside windows](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)
3. [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)